# Need PECL OAUTH-1.0.0 windows dll

Tags: pecl

Anyone know where a windows dll for PECL OAUTH-1.0.0?

(0.99.9 is here http://downloads.php.net/pierre/)

Answer (score 2):

Its already there.

```
http://downloads.php.net/pierre/php_oauth-1.1.1-dev-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.zip
```

Comment: What's the difference between `php_oauth-1.1.1-dev-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.zip` and `php_oauth-1.1.1-dev-5.3-vc9-x86.zip`?